# Minha aplicação não inicia no Spring-Tools Suite

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Criei um projeto maven no Spring-Tools Suite quando fui iniciar aparece este erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to read Class-Path attribute from manifest of jar file:/C:/Users/Manoel/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.fromUrlClassLoader(ChangeableUrls.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getInitialUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.<init>(Restarter.java:139)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:539)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartedEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:45)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.started(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1187)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1176)
    at com.algaworks.vinhos.AwVinhosApplication.main(AwVinhosApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:99)
    ... 16 more
```

Segue a classe `AwVinhosApplication`

```
package com.algaworks.vinhos;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication 
public class AwVinhosApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AwVinhosApplication.class, args);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Parece um jar corrompido. Você está usando Maven? Talvez seja uma boa deletar o conte'udo da pasta `~/.m2/repository/*` (veja: [essa resposta do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11711153/664577))

Comment: @Anthony. Estou usando o maven, nao estou encontrando esta pasta

Comment: Esta pasta ".m2" fica oculta tem que habilitar na visualização do windows para mostrar. Ficam em C:/Users/Usuario/.m2

Comment: Abra o seu gerenciador de arquivos (e.g., Windows Explorer ou Nautilus) e navegue até a pasta do seu usuário (e.g., `C:\User\JoseLemo`). A pasta `.m2` pode estar invisível mas você consegue navegar até ela de qualquer forma digitando o caminho (e.g., `C:\User\JoseLemo\.m2`). Tente deletar o conteúdo da pasta `repository` e construir o projeto (`mvn clean install`) novamente.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Deu tudo certo :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
```

Costuma significar que um ou mais jars estão corrompidos.

O Maven, por padrão faz download e guarda esses jars na pasta `~/.m2/repository/*`. Para resolver o problema apague o conteúdo da pasta e rode `mvn clean install` novamente.

**Obs:** No Windows a pasta `.m2` por padrão fica invisível. Para encontrá-la, assumindo configurações padrões no Maven, abra o seu gerenciador de arquivos e navegue até a pasta do seu usuário (e.g., `C:\User\MeuUsuario`). Mesmo que a pasta `.m2` não esteja visível você consegue navegar até ela digitando o caminho (e.g., `C:\User\MeuUsuario\.m2\repository`).

---

**Fonte**: [SOen - Maven invalid LOC header (bad signature)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32090921/664577)

Comment: Estou com o mesmo erro, fiz tudo como falou mas ao rodar o comando "mvn clean install" aparece -bash: mvn: command not found. Sou usuário de MAC.

Comment: Oi Fernando. Versões recentes do macOS não vêm com o Maven pré-instalado. O STS usa uma versão embarcada por padrão. Assumindo que seu projeto usa o Maven, as opções são instalar o Maven our usar o próprio STS para reconstruir o projeto.

Answer (score 0):

tive esse mesmo problema com esse projeto da Algawoks. Solucionei trocando a versao do Hibernate no pom.xml
ficou assim apos as alterações. 

        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        1.5.3.RELEASE

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
```

io.jsonwebtoken
    jjwt
    0.7.0

        
            org.springframework.boot
            spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
        
        
            org.springframework.boot
            spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf
        
    
      org.postgresql
      postgresql

```
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```